# How to map Date @WebParam in JAX-WS to xsd:date instead of xsd:datetime?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have the following interface that represents a remote webservice I am consuming.

```
@WebService(name="ws_listadosPort", portName="ws_listadosPort", targetNamespace="...")
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC, use=Use.ENCODED, parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface TheService {

    @WebMethod(operationName="someMethod")
    @WebResult(partName="return") 
    String someMethod(@WebParam(name="when", partName="when")  Date when);

}
```

I am creating a webservice client simply by doing

```
QName serviceName = new QName(namespace, "ws_listados");
QName portTypeName = new QName(namespace, "ws_listadosPort");
Service service = Service.create(new URL(wsdlLocation), serviceName);
TheService servicePort = service.getPort(portTypeName, TheService.class);
```

and invoking the desired method. However, when checking the envelope produced (through fiddler) I notice "when" parameter is sent as an xsd:dateTime

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:someMethod xmlns:ns2="..."><when>2014-04-21T12:00:00-03:00</when></ns2:someMethod>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

And the wsdl I am referencing states that when parameter is an xsd:date, not an xsd:dateTime.

```
<message name="someMethodRequest">
  <part name="when" type="xsd:date" />
</message>

<portType name="ws_listadosPortType">
  <operation name="someMethod">
    <input message="tns:someMethodRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:someMethodResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
```

I am using Jersey's implementation of JAX-WS. How can I tweak my annotations (or even my parameters data types) in order to generate a request with the "when" parameter encoded as a xsd:date not as a xsd:dateType?